# Android Horizontal RecyclerView with ListViews as items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[List wireframe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz20x.jpg)
I'm trying to build a list like the one in the picture where I have a horizontal RecyclerView with ListViews (or RecyclerViews) as items. Can you give me an example on how to build this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Book> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getNextItems();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(data, this, recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void getNextItems() {
        int itemCount = data.size();
        for (int i = itemCount; i <= itemCount + 5; i++) {
            Book book = new Book();
            book.title = "Title " + i;
            book.author = "Author " + i;
            book.description = "Description " + i;
            data.add(book);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dp"
    tools:context="com.example.sabari.recyclerviewsample.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by sabari on 2/8/2016.
 */
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    public static final String Name = "Name";
    public static final String Author = "Author";
    public static final String Description = "Description";
    private List<Book> dataSet;
    private Context context;

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Book> data, Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ListView listView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            listView = (ListView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.book_layout, parent, false);

        vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {
//                Binding Views...
            ArrayList<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
            for (Book book : dataSet) {
                HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
                hashMap.put(Name, book.title);
                hashMap.put(Author, book.author);
                hashMap.put(Description, book.description);
                list.add(hashMap);
            }

            ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(context, list);
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
}
```

ListViewAdapter.java (Ref: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by sabari on 2/13/2016.
 */
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public static final String Name = "Name";
    public static final String Author = "Author";
    public static final String Description = "Description";
    public ArrayList<HashMap> list;
    Context context;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap> list) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView author;
        TextView description;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.author = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        HashMap map = list.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(map.get(Name).toString());
        holder.author.setText(map.get(Author).toString());
        holder.description.setText(map.get(Description).toString());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Book.java

```
   public class Book {
        String title;
        String author;
        String description;
    }
```

book_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Custom drawable - border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#2B91B4" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Excellent. Just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: How do you control the number of ListViews created?

Comment: In MainActivity I am creating List<Book> list and pass it to RecyclerViewAdapter. In RecyclerViewAdapter I am converting List<Book> to ArrayList<HashMap> and passing this ArrayList<HashMap>  to ListViewAdapter, here I am taking ArrayList<HashMap> size to create ListViews.  @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

Comment: Here you have to modify the code as depend on your project.

Comment: The getCount() method controls the number of items in the ListView. I was looking to control the number of items in the RecyclerView (the number of VList elements from the picture) but based on your response I figured it's the getItemCount() method which makes sense but somehow I missed it at first. Thanks again, you helped me a lot!