# RecyclerView with multiple view types added programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a client-server application and I get all my data from the server. Thus in one entity there may be an array of photos, for example. I don't know how many there will be so I can't just create one view type. I will need to create each view programmatically. How can I add custom created views to my `RecyclerView` without using XML?

Comment: Then where do you plan to get the XML from? You can create multiple XML files and inflate each in a different `ViewHolder`, but you still need to have a list of layouts to inflate in advance.

Comment: @NeriaNachum I'm planning to create custom views inside code with the `addView` method

Comment: You are saying one entity can have array of photos ... then you can take Gridview or listview as item of your Recyclerview

Comment: @Pramod ok, that sounds good. Do I access the list (and thus add images) in `ViewHolder` constructor?

Comment: In ViewHolder create array/list data structure  bindviewholder inflate the listview for each item and set adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above use listview as item of your Recyclerview for more details check this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371965/472336

Answer (score 0):

In the layout representing a row, have a LinearLayout.

Then add your image dynamically to the layout:

```
//ImageView Setup
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

//setting image resource
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.whatever);

//setting image position
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

//adding view to the linearLayout which is inside your row layout
linearLayout.addView(imageView);
```

And loop if needed !